# React TypeScript with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to ask for help. How can I be able to render these menus under their correct and proper category menu? Currently, they would just pile against each other instead of rendering from their proper menu.  I am using React together with TypeScript and I have been working for this nonstop and haven't found an answer. Hope someone could help.

This is a sample photo of the problem. They're all overlapping and rendering together instead of rendering it differently from the other menu.

[image]

- This Message Menu would only render a Menu List drop down menu.

[image]

- This Operation Menu would and should only render Ack, Unack, Clear, and Comment

Here's my source code.

```
const handleClick = (index: null, event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
};

<Menu
  id="basic-menu"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  open={open}
  onClose={handleClose}
  MenuListProps={{
    "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
  }}
>
  {customtoolinfo.menu_sub.map((custommenusubtool: any) => (
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
      {custommenusubtool.menu_sub_name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you have same `anchorEl` value of all sub menus. This issue can be fixed in many ways. One way is to have only one menu and render it's sub-menus based on condition or second way is to have different `anchorEl` state for every submenu and control them based on menu